# check if type(A)==type(B) OR type(A)==type(B with removed constness) briefly

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I create a matrix view over a vector storage of elements.

Valid combinations are:

| vector `value_type` | matrix `value_type` |
| --- | --- |
| const (arithmetic) | const (arithmetic) |
| (arithmetic) | const (arithmetic) |
| (arithmetic) | (arithmetic) |

So, a typical matrix constructor can be:

```
template<std::contiguous_iterator It>
requires(std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, value_type> ||
         std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, std::remove_const_t<value_type>>)
matrix(It it) requires(H != -1 && view) : elements(std::to_address(it)) {}
```

Can I do this a little bit more brief/short/laconic with an std facility?

I tried `std::convertible_to<const double, double&>` for testing and it does the job, but then I tried `std::convertible_to<const double, const int&>` and it does not failed as I want.

Comment: You don't need the first part of your `||` statement. `remove_const_t`, when there is no `const`ness, will just return the type.

Comment: @ChrisMM in that case, first valid combination will not pass.

Comment: My mistake, I somehow missed the table you have in the question. Apparently I need my eyes checked :)

Comment: @Chameleon: Can't you just put these in a concept? That's what concepts are for: bundles of requirements.